# this is the error error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am reading data from firebase database and getting this error.
I am new and following an old course on udemy and this got me stuck. Please help thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class Users {
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? phone;
  String? name;

  Users({this.id, this.email, this.phone, this.name});

  Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key!;

    email = dataSnapshot.value!["email"];
    name = dataSnapshot.value?["name"];
    phone = dataSnapshot.value?["phone"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class Users {
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? phone;
  String? name;

  Users({this.id, this.email, this.phone, this.name});

  Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key!;
    var data = dataSnapshot.value as Map?;
    
    if(data != null){
      email = data!["email"];
      name = data?["name"];
      phone = data?["phone"];
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you it helped!